# Using assertTrue() to validate the presence of text in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, assert

I want to validate the presence of a text using assertTrue(), but I am getting a StackOverflow error. I am not sure that the code I have written is correct or not. Need your suggestions.

```
// Checking the posted text
WebElement postedtext= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css123"));
assertTrue("The text is verfied",postedtext.getText().equals(enteredText));

private static void assertTrue(String string, boolean equals) {
assertTrue(string,equals);}
```

Comment: Are you using `TestNG` or `Junit`? Logically I don't see any issue in this code block. OP have declared and invoked the same `assertTrue(String string, boolean equals)`. No reason for atleast `TestNG` to interfere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a name conflicting that you happened to name you assert method the same name as the library method. Rename your `assertTrue` can solve the problem.

```
// Checking the posted text
WebElement postedtext= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css123"));
myAssertTrue("The text is verfied",postedtext.getText().equals(enteredText));

private static void myAssertTrue(String string, boolean equals) {
    try {
        assertTrue(string,equals);
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Or you just delete your `assertTrue` and use the library method instead.

Comment: It did the job. But I am not getting the string message in console. Is the string message suppose to come in console or we have to do something else here ?

Comment: @Alapan Das You have to catch ```AssertionError``` and get message from the error, I have updated my code.

Answer (score 3):

You have a method called `assertTrue(s, b)` which calls itself. This is causing an infinite recursion.

Comment: What can I do here?

Comment: Delete your implementation of `assertTrue()` and simply call the one provided by your testing library (JUnit or whatever).